# How to rotate orientation?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I want to rotate orientation when I switch from `UINavigationController` in portrait mode to `UIViewController` to landscape mode, but it doesn't work.

I tried

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!.rootViewController = playModeVc
```

but I can see the next viewController in portrait, but I want to see it in landscape mode. When I use

```
present(playModeVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

it doesn't deallocate memory.

I want to deallocate memory when I switch viewController. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from your question is that you want to force one view controller to always appear in landscape mode.

Here is how to do it in **Swift 3**. Add this code to the view controller that you want to appear in landscape:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {  
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape  
}  

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {  
    return false  
}
```

Comment: I did it, but it doesn't work... I have 4 ViewControllers in portrait mode, but I need one controller in landscape...